# DllNotFoundException in Mono on a Mac

Tags: ios, mono, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build my unity applicaton on a mac but I have the following error:

> DllNotFoundException: libMonoPosixHelper.dylib

I've googled around but can't seem to find a fix for this issue. Has anyone ever come across this before? How did you get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you're using **Unity3d Free**, correct?

Dynamic including of Dll's is **not** a feature of the free-version, you'll ned to buy **Unity Pro**

If your not including a dll on your own, then maybe the installation is broken

Comment: I'm using the pro version of unity and the install was done for me (not my computer). Other guys have developed on this computer just fine. For some reason it hates me.

Comment: From somewhere I know this feeling ;) But I dont guess i can help you out, when i had the problem it was because my trial has expired

Comment: It was a good shout. I did need to check to make sure I'm using the pro version.